# windows 7 search results columns "Folder", "Folder name", "Folder path" empty

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-search

How can I see the folder\file path when searching on a connected device?
I have selected to show "Folder", "Folder name", "Folder path" columns but they all appear empty.
[image]

Comment: What sort of connected device? Are those images on a USB drive? Camera? ...?

Comment: It's my smartphone connected using USB cable.

Comment: That probably explains it then, although I don't know the exact reason for it nor how to override this default behaviour. If the files are on an SD card then you can always use an external card reader.

Comment: I've decided to use an externall tool. FileSearchEX works just fine.

Comment: That's a wise choice I'd say, since Windows Search (AQS) is limited or broken in so many ways.